# How to sort end array by COLUMN_POSITION?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am looping over an array of values building another array as the code below shows:

```
foreach ($mdl->info()['metadata'] as $info) {
    $fields[] = [
        'name'    => strtolower($info['COLUMN_NAME']),
        'title'   => ucfirst(strtolower($info['COLUMN_NAME'])),
        'type'    => $grid_type_mapper[$info['DATA_TYPE']],
        'width'   => $info['LENGTH'],
        'sorting' => true,
        'editing' => false,
    ];
}
```

One of the key existing on `$info` is `COLUMN_POSITION` and I want to sort the resulting array `$fields` by this `COLUMN_POSITION`, how?

Comment: `usort()` is probably good to look at.. *"sort the resulting array `$fields` by this ..... "*. - sort in what way? You are not specifying that.

Comment: @Nytrix `COLUMN_POSITION` is just a number I want to sort by such number DESC

Comment: Note: your code doesn't show `$info['COLUMN_POSITION']` being copied to the new array, so sorting by it is going to be (unnecessarily) tricky. Add it in, sort by it, and then loop through and `unset()` it from each element if it's really necessary for it not to be in the final result..

Comment: If `COLUMN_POSITION` is unique, you can use it as the key as you build `$fields`, and then `krsort`.